# Re-label healthy (0) as failure (1) examples using PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I wanted to re-label healthy examples (0) as failure (1) for 2 days before the actual failure for all serial numbers in the failure column. Here is my code:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('spark3.2show').getOrCreate()
print('Spark info :')
spark

url="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JishanAhmed2019/e464ca4da5c871428ca9ed9264467aa0/raw/da3921c1953fefbc66dddc3ce238dac53142dba8/failure.csv"
from pyspark import SparkFiles
spark.sparkContext.addFile(url)
df=spark.read.csv(SparkFiles.get("failure.csv"), header=True,sep='\t')
```

I wanted to re-label the red marked 0 as 1. Also, Serial C was mistakenly present in the database as healthy even after the actual failure.

[image]

Comment: You can please make your question more understandable. What is the meaning of `relabel` - want to replace/update row values or derive new column with updated values? What you want to do with `Serial C`?

Comment: Can you also add what you've tried and what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recast the date column as a `Timestamp` because this will allow you to take the difference between any two Timestamps, which we will need to do.

Then you can create a new column called `failure_dates` that contains the date whenever a failure occurs, and is `null` otherwise.

Next, create a new column called `2_days_to_failure` where you partition by `serial_number` and take the difference between the max value in the `failure_date` column each date inside the partition to get the number of days to failure, returning 1 whenever there is 2 days or fewer to failure.

Finally, we can create a column called `failure_relabeled` by combining the information from the columns `2_days_to_failure` and the original `failure` column.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number

window  = Window.partitionBy("serial_number")

df.withColumn(
    'date', F.to_timestamp(F.col('date'), 'M/D/yyyy')
).withColumn(
    "failure_dates", F.when(F.col('failure') == 1, F.col('date'))
).withColumn(
    "2_days_to_failure", F.datediff(F.max(F.col('failure_dates')).over(window), F.col('date')) <= 2
).withColumn(
    "failure_relabeled", F.when((F.col('2_days_to_failure') | (F.col('failure') == 1)), F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))
).orderBy('serial_number','date').show()

+-------------------+-------------+-------+-----------+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|               date|serial_number|failure|smart_5_raw|smart_187_raw|      failure_dates|2_days_to_failure|failure_relabeled|
+-------------------+-------------+-------+-----------+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|2014-01-01 00:00:00|            A|      0|          0|           60|               null|            false|                0|
|2014-01-02 00:00:00|            A|      0|          0|          180|               null|            false|                0|
|2014-01-03 00:00:00|            A|      0|          0|          140|               null|             true|                1|
|2014-01-04 00:00:00|            A|      0|          0|          280|               null|             true|                1|
|2014-01-05 00:00:00|            A|      1|          0|          400|2014-01-05 00:00:00|             true|                1|
|2014-01-01 00:00:00|            B|      0|          0|           40|               null|             null|                0|
|2014-01-02 00:00:00|            B|      0|          0|          160|               null|             null|                0|
|2014-01-03 00:00:00|            B|      0|          0|          100|               null|             null|                0|
|2014-01-04 00:00:00|            B|      0|          0|          320|               null|             null|                0|
|2014-01-05 00:00:00|            B|      0|          0|          340|               null|             null|                0|
|2014-01-06 00:00:00|            B|      0|          0|          400|               null|             null|                0|
|2014-01-01 00:00:00|            C|      0|          0|           80|               null|             true|                1|
|2014-01-02 00:00:00|            C|      0|          0|          200|               null|             true|                1|
|2014-01-03 00:00:00|            C|      1|          0|          120|2014-01-03 00:00:00|             true|                1|
|2014-01-04 00:00:00|            D|      0|          0|          300|               null|             null|                0|
|2014-01-05 00:00:00|            D|      0|          0|          360|               null|             null|                0|
+-------------------+-------------+-------+-----------+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: I needed to all 2 days as 1. For example, A's failure date is 5th January, so I want to re-label 4th and 3rd January's 0 label as 1. Current code is showing 1 only for 5th and 3rd January. Same is true for all other serial_number.

Comment: @ForestGump okay we can change `F.col('date')) == 2` to `F.col('date')) <= 2`. i've updated my answer